# Grouping a list into a list of lists in F#

Tags: f#

Okay so I'm lost on this one. I have a list of objects. Each object as a non-unique ID in it. I want to group on this ID but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do this.

This is what I have

```
type fooObject = {
     Id : int
     Info : string
}

let fooObjects: fooObject list
```

The data might look something like this

```
[ { Id = 1 ; Data = "foo" } ; { Id = 1 ; Data = "also foo" } ; { Id = 2 ; Data = "Not foo" } ]
```

I would like something like

```
let fooObjectsGroupedById : fooObject list list
```

So the final result would look like this

```
[ [{ Id = 1 ; Data = "foo" } ; { Id = 1 ; Data = "also foo" } ] ; [{ Id = 2 ; Data = "Not foo" }]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `List.groupBy`:

```
let groupById fooObjects =
    List.groupBy (fun foo -> foo.Id) fooObjects
        |> List.map snd
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is snd?

Comment: `snd` is used because `groupBy` returns a list of tuples, where the first item is the grouping key (in your case, the Id values), and the second tuple item is the list of all matches. The function [`snd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.snd%5B't1,'t2%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) pulls the second item from a tuple